How to call a (select...) column with a "..." name?
I want to give a (select...) column with a certain name that require double quotation marks, but i want to call this column in a WHERE clause or in a HAVING clause.
Here's what i'm trying:
select emp_id ID,
concat(fname, ' ', lname) AS "Nome do funcionário",
(select sum(titles.pub_id = E.pub_id) from titles) AS "Número de livros publicados"
    from employee AS E
    where "Número de livros publicados" = 7;

I managed to do it using the HAVING clause, but i had to change "Número de livros publicados" to Total , but I did want the other alias.
select emp_id AS ID,
concat(fname, ' ', lname) AS "Nome do funcionário",
(select sum(titles.pub_id = E.pub_id) from titles) AS Total
    from employee E
    having Total = 7;

What it returns:

Is there a way to do it without changing its alias?

A simple trick would be to make a subquery to select all results and give aliases there, then surround it with outer query, which applies WHERE clause, recognizing the quoted text as a column name of the subquery. It will, however, worsen its performance somehow.
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT E.emp_id AS ID,
    concat(E.fname, ' ', E.lname) AS "Nome do funcionário",
    COUNT(*) AS "Número de livros publicados"
  FROM employee AS E
  JOIN titles AS T USING (pub_id)
  GROUP BY E.emp_id ) AS values
WHERE "Número de livros publicados" = 7;


Here's how I would write the query:
SELECT E.emp_id AS ID,
  concat(E.fname, ' ', E.lname) AS "Nome do funcionário",
  COUNT(*) AS "Número de livros publicados"
FROM employee AS E
JOIN titles AS T USING (pub_id)
GROUP BY E.emp_id
HAVING "Número de livros publicados" = 7;


Note that by default MySQL does not use double-quotes as identifier delimiters. By default, double-quotes are the same as single-quotes, acting as string literal delimiters.
Comparing a string literal to an integer 7 is probably not going to match, so this may be why you got no rows returned.
The default identifier delimiter in MySQL is a back-tick:
SELECT E.emp_id AS ID,
  concat(E.fname, ' ', E.lname) AS `Nome do funcionário`,
  COUNT(*) AS `Número de livros publicados`
FROM employee AS E
JOIN titles AS T USING (pub_id)
GROUP BY E.emp_id
HAVING `Número de livros publicados` = 7;

To make double-quotes act as in the standard SQL way, you must change the sql_mode option to include ANSI_QUOTES or ANSI.
To make this even more confusing, defining aliases may use either identifier delimiters or string delimiters, but referencing aliases elsewhere in the query must treat them as identifiers. I have no idea why this is so inconsistent in MySQL.

I think this way also works, but the problem is on the HAVING condition. It's trying to check if the text "Número de livros publicados" is equal to 7, so it returns a empty list. The program doest recognizes "Número de livros publicados" as the alias of COUNT(*). It would work with HAVING COUNT(*) = 7, but this just runs from my problem.
